# How to add a myOwn-background image to QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit

For example, if you create a simple plaintextedit, the background is just white. How do I change white background with my own image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In design edit, you can set the styleSheet in properties of `QWidget`. In c++ code you can set the background using `QSS`, for example, setting
‍‍‍‍`background-image: URL("path/image.png");`:

`myWidget->setStyleSheet("background-image: URL('path/image.png')");`

Comment: And what kind of modules should be installed from maintaining tool for that to work?

Comment: Qt Core, Qt Gui, Qt Widgets, with default installation you can work.